# Is it possible to use Material Design for Bootstrap in react js using npm?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-design

I need to use https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/ for my web app. I can see npm version also available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-material-design. I am looking for a better solution and guidelines to use it in react. I had looked MDB i.e https://mdbootstrap.com/. This UI kit having react version. But compared to first one, this is a little bit less attractive. Can any help me out this?

Comment: Well, it seems `bootstrap-material-design` does not have a React integration. If you need a react styling library that follows material design, use [material-ui.](https://material-ui.com/)

Comment: I have already used Material UI in some other project. That is great UI kit for react. But I am looking for Bootstrap combined with Material UI. So I can use Bootstrap components and Utilities with Material UI design effects.